# How to merge multiple list using flat map with null and empty check in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm merging multiple list using `Stream.of(..)` & then performing `flatMap` on the same to collect the combined list as below:

```
class Foo{

    List<Entity> list1;
    List<Entity> list2;
    List<Entity> list3;

    //getters & setters

}
```

```
Foo foo = getFoo();
Predicate<Entity> isExist = //various conditions on foo ;
List<Bar> bars = Stream
        .of(foo.getList1(), foo.getList2(), foo.getList3())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(isExist)
        .map(entity -> getBar(entity))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**First question**:

Does `Stream.of(..)` checks  `nonNull` & `notEmpty`?
If ans is **No** then,

**Second Question**:

How can I perform the `nonNull` & `notEmpty` checks on all the `lists` I'm getting from `foo` in the above code ?So that whenever merge of all these three list happens, it will basically ignore the `null` & `empty` `list` to avoid `NullPointerException` ?

Comment: @Adrian *checks on all the lists I'm getting from foo*... seems like _before_, not _after_ `flatMap`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 Stream
    .of(foo.getList1(), foo.getList2(), foo.getList3())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    ....
```

Or as pointed by Holger and specified in the `flatMap` java-doc:

> If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.

thus, you could do:

```
 Stream
    .of(foo.getList1(), foo.getList2(), foo.getList3())
    .flatMap(x -> x == null? null : x.stream())
```

Comment: Maybe you should have answered the first part of the question first. Since `flatMap` will do the right thing for empty lists, there is no need to test it. So for the second part of the question, a `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before the `flatMap` would be sufficient. Or just use a single `.flatMap(list -> list == null? null: list.stream())`.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. So it means if `foo.getList1()` is `null` then `flatMap` will consider it as a `emptyList` correct ? And if the `foo.getList1()` is empty then it will just ignore while doing flatMap, is that correct ? or I missed something in understanding ?

Comment: @AshwinK right, this is what the documentation says, after all. an empty Stream, not an empty List

Comment: @Eugene Got it. I was referring to just the documentation of `.of(...)`. I do have one query: Whenever we just do `list.stream().map(some mapping).collect(Collectors.toList());` & if `list` is `null` then it throws exception. But is it not the case with `Stream.of(...)` ?

Comment: @AshwinK sorry I don't understand your question - you might want to post another one

Comment: `Stream.of(foo.getList1(), foo.getList2(), foo.getList3())` will not throw any exception even if `foo.getList1()` is `NULL`, correct ?

Comment: @AshwinK before asking, you could have tried... but it will _not_

Comment: @Holger Wondering if `Stream.ofNullable` could have supported varargs as well such that it would have `return`ed `Arrays.stream(values).filter(Objects::nonNull)`. Not sure why it wasn't overloaded same as `Stream.of` though.

Comment: @Naman exactly. Now I understood, `Stream.of(..)`  & `stream()` works different with null. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AshwinK it’s not so different. `Stream.of(…)` doesn’t care what elements you provide. The fact that you are passing `List` elements, is irrelevant. When you chain `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` unconditionally, it’s equivalent to `.flatMap(list list.stream())`, which would fail when encountering `null`, as every method invocation does. But when you use `.flatMap(x -> x == null? null : x.stream())`, you’re handling the `null` case, by mapping a `null` list to a `null` stream, which `flatMap` is guaranteed to handle like an empty stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holger it helped to clear a lot of concepts.